# cakePHP Left Join Main Model in hasMany Relationship Using $options Array causes error

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

Ok. This must be an easy one for you cakePHP ninjas out there! But my cakePHP skills are still pretty much at the lowest level.  So I have 2 Models; Donor Model, and Donations Model.

The setup is as follows :

Donor Model hasMany Donation Model

Donor Model

```
public $hasMany = array(
        'Donation' => array(
            'className' => 'Donation',
            'foreignKey' => 'donor_id',
            'order' => 'Donation.created DESC',
            'limit' => 10,
            'dependent' => true
        )
    );
```

Now in the DonorsController I am using the paginatorComponent's paginate() method. Within my index I have this code

```
 public function index($id = null){
        $options['joins'] = array(
            array(
            'table' => 'donations',
            'alias' => 'Donation',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Donor.id = Donation.donor_id',
            ))
        );
        $donors = $this->Paginator->paginate('Donor',$options);
        $this->set('donors',$donors);      
    }
```

However this returns an sql Error : 
'1054 Unknown column 'joins' in 'where clause' ''

Anyone knows why this is happening, Or if the above code is correct? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is incorrect, please see the below function:

```
   public function index($id = null){
            $options['joins'] = array(
                array(
                'table' => 'donations',
                'alias' => 'Donation',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Donor.id = Donation.donor_id',
                ))
            );
            $this->paginate = $options;
            $donors = $this->Paginator->paginate('Donor');
            $this->set('donors',$donors);      
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhav! So I take it that the paginate method does not accept the $options parameter as with the find() method